# Which will be the best UX to show three channel report, including sub items like the below screenshot

Tags: usability

I want to create a view to show three channel traffic report with the sub menus.

- SMS
- WhatsApp
- Voice
- Email

In the Channel SMS menu We have further categorization
**SMS**

- PUSH
- PULL
- OTP

and another chnnel have also further categories
**WhatsAPP**

- PUSH
- OTP

and so on.

In each subcategories have the lots of reports. So I have designed this, if anyone have any idea which will be the best way to show this within this themes.

[image]

Like I have an !dea what i have presented to it

Comment: it looks good for me, what kind of objectives do you want to achieve?

Comment: Thank you @fansuriarrumi, Objective is to merge the TA report for both SMS and Vocie in one Login but it should differenciate in which section you are it means one by one you can choose sms or Voice and see their reports. In one time you can only select one Channel.

Answer (score 1):

based on what you have described I feel that you have done what is needed for visualisation of report data. However, you may like to consider the following points to make some improvements/ adjustments to the design:

1. If the report data can be represented in graphical manner and is time based, you may like to refer to how Google ads/ Analytics dashboard are like - they provide a good overview of analytics data on the ad performance and customisation of reports (a feature usually present when there is a lot of parameters available)
2. Because there are a lot of parameters, new users may not understand what the parameters mean, and sometimes experienced users may also forget what the data represent. So in the reporting tables you can consider having small help icons that provide hints on what the data represent when users mouseover them.
3. It's good that you placed the WhatsApp/ SMS/ Voice/ Email channel on the top within a dropdown box. This makes it really clear which channel the reports are from. This differentiation can be enhanced using color codings if the overall visual design of the software allows for it.

Hope these suggestions help!